# CakePHP wizard component / tutorial for version 1.3

Tags: cakephp

can someone please point me in the right direction, I am looking for a tutorial on how to create a form wizard in cakephp version 1.3

Thanks for your answers in advance.
Louis

Comment: May be http://thecodemine.org/ can help you to create your form wizard.

Comment: @Arun Jain - Thank you for the suggestion, this is a very interesting jquery plugin and it might just do what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Form Wizard Jquery Plugin](http://thecodemine.org/). This is somehow same what you might need.